# SQL Server - Manipulate data and return new results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to do something in SQL Server to manipulate data like manipulating arrays in any other programming language?

I have one SQL query that returns 3 columns, "dt_ref" (date), "vlr_venda" (float) and "qt_parcelas" (int)

Basically, I need to do something like this:

```
- When field "qt_parcelas" is higher than 1, I need to do a "loop" with this row and generate 3 rows.
```

So,  I need to divide the field "vlr_venda" by field "qt_parcelas", and use the field "dt_ref" as reference for the date start and increment month in the date field for the value of "qt_parcelas"

For example, if my query returns these structure:

```
        | dt_ref | vlr_venda | qt_parcelas  |
        -------------------------------------
        |20180901 | 3000         | 3        |
```

I need to do something to return this:

```
        | dt_ref | vlr_venda | 
        ----------------------
        |20180901 | 1000     |
        |20181001 | 1000     |
        |20181101 | 1000     |
```

Is it possible to do it in SQL Server?
I've searched for something like this but haven't found anything useful...
Any ideas?

Comment: This is the sort of business logic you probably don't want to do in pure SQL. Not just because it's slightly inconvenient (requiring a tally table or recursion) because you can work with that, but because there are better languages and better coding environments for expressing and recording them, especially if demands become more complicated over time. It's fine if this is a one-time transformation; not so much if you have to do this continuously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE: [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c7adb/1)

```
with cte as (
      select dt_ref, vlr_venda / qt_parcelas as new_val, qt_parcelas, 1 as num
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dt_ref), new_val, qt_parcelas, num + 1
      from cte
      where num < qt_parcelas
     )
select dt_ref, new_val
from cte;
```

As written, this will work for up to 100 months.  You need to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` for longer periods.

Comment: Thanks! Just what i need! 
And this SQLFiddle is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a rCTE you could use a tally table. If you have much larger numbers than 3 this'll probably be far be efficient:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT n
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(n)),
Tally AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) I
    FROM N N1 --10 rows
         CROSS JOIN N N2 --100 rows
         --CROSS JOIN N N3 --Keep adding more CROSS JOINs to create more rows
         ),
VTE AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(date,V.dt_ref) AS dt_ref,
           V.vlr_venda,
           V.qt_parcelas
    FROM (VALUES('20180901',3000,3),
                ('20181001',12000,6)) V(dt_ref,vlr_venda ,qt_parcelas))
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,T.I,V.dt_ref),
       CONVERT(decimal(10,4),V.vlr_venda / (V.qt_parcelas * 1.0)) --incase you need decimal points

FROM VTE V
     JOIN Tally T ON V.qt_parcelas >= T.I;
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed a software to generate tickets and i had a similar experience than you. I have tried CURSORS and recursive CTE and they all took something like 50 minutes when creating tickets for clients

I used this function to replicate my clients and generate my tickets

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[NumbersTable]    Script Date: 28/09/2018 10:51:25 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NumbersTable] (
  @fromNumber int,
  @toNumber int,
  @byStep int
)
RETURNS @NumbersTable TABLE (i int)
AS
BEGIN

  WITH CTE_NumbersTable AS (

    SELECT @fromNumber AS i

    UNION ALL

    SELECT i + @byStep
    FROM CTE_NumbersTable
    WHERE
      (i + @byStep) <= @toNumber
  )
  INSERT INTO @NumbersTable
  SELECT i FROM CTE_NumbersTable OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

  RETURN;
END 
GO
```

Then you can use a

```
CROSS APPLY dbo.NumbersTable(1,qt_parcelas ,1);
```

To generate your rows

Believe me this way is more efficient and when dealing with large amount of data (something like 8 to 10 million rows) it takes something like 2 minutes instead of 40

Comment: This would )probably) be much better as a inline table-value function. You're basically there, so not sure why you chose to go down the multi-line option. :)